# Redirecting URLs with mod_rewrite

Tags: web-server, ssl, mod-rewrite, ssl-certificate

I am trying to setup a website where we would like to redirect the URL for a couple of different cases.  The cases are below:

- If port 80 then force port 443
- If URL = `support.example.com` then force URL = `support.example-1.com`

We would like to first require all traffic to be on HTTPS and then require that one of our domains (since it resolves to the same box and due to our SSL certificate) is redirected to another one of our domains.  We are able to get the force SSL to work, but we cannot seem to find a mod_rewrite rule that will work when `https://support.example.com` is requested to force it to `https://support.example-1.com`.

Any help that you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you "_first_ require all traffic to be on HTTPS" and the "SSL certificate" is not valid for that domain then you'll obviously get browser security warning. So, you should do it the other way round, redirect to `example-1.com` _first_. Or include an exception in the preceding HTTP to HTTPS rule block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done the force SSL so ignoring that.

`RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^support\.example\.com$

RewriteRule (.*) https://support.example-1.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Did I just delete your comment by accident? Apologies if so. I'm going to assume you did it but if not let me know :)

Comment: I am not able to get that set of rules that you listed to work.  It does not seem to redirect.  If I start out with https://support.example.com then I am not redirected to https://support.example-1.com.  I have added the rules that you listed to my SSL virtual host.  I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: It works for me inside a .htaccess - I have the following in the .htaccess for *.jdlawrie.co.uk and it redirects test.jdlawrie.co.uk: `RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.jdlawrie\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://test.com/$1 [R=302,L]`. Did you ensure you got your <Location> tags in the vhost file? Paste the configuration and I'll try to help.